# Все комбинации элементов списка python - функциональный стиль

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, комбинаторика, функциональное-программирование

Требуется функция, которая возвращает список, со всевозможными комбинациями элементов входящего списка, но написанная в **функциональном стиле**. То есть без присваивания, циклов... Рекурсия приветствуется.

Для примера, у меня есть похожая, но она возвращает не все значения:

```
def f (s, n):
    return [s[:n+1]]+[s[n+1:]]

def f2 (s, n):
    return [] if n > len(s)-1 else f(s,n) + f2(s,n+1)

print(f2([1,2,3,0))
```

Возвращает:

```
[[1], [2, 3], [1, 2], [3], [1, 2, 3], []]
```

А мне требуется:

```
[[], [1], [2], [3], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не очень эффективно, но работает:

```
def prepend(e, lists):
    if len(lists) == 0:
        return []
    return [[e] + lists[0]] + prepend(e, lists[1:])


def duplicate(e, lists):
    return lists + prepend(e, lists)


def f(s):
    if len(s) == 0:
        return [[]]
    return duplicate(s[0], f(s[1:]))


print(f([1,2,3]))
```

Comment: Работать то работает. Да вот к сожалению функция у вас не в функциональном стиле, а для меня это ключевое

Comment: В решении смесь функционального стиля и генератора. Вам не нравится генератор?

Comment: цикл, в нём проблема. Мне требуется функция без `for`. Переписать бы это рекурсивно, было бы отлично

Comment: Поправил. Стало ещё медленнее. Но это уже чистый лисп.

Comment: Отлично! Скорость мне не особо важна, спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

```
import functools

def f(it):
    return functools.reduce(lambda y, x: y + [z + [x] for z in y], it, [[]])
```

```
print(f([1, 2, 3])) # [[], [1], [2], [1, 2], [3], [1, 3], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

И на всякий случай: `for` здесь не цикл, а генератор списка, т.е. функциональная конструкция. Но если очень хочется, можно заменить на `map`.